# Table Pagination : How can I create a table with 10 elements and implement first, previous, next and last button?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm trying to create table with id, firstName, and lastName. Storing only 10 elements per page and implement the first, previous, next, last page button.

How will I be able to implement 10 elements per page given the code below? And how to implement the first, previous, next, last page button?

```
import React from 'react';

import data from './data';

const USERS_URL = data.results;

export default function Table() {
    return (
        <div>
            <table className="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>First Name</th>
                        <th>Last Name</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {USERS_URL.map(d => {
                        return (
                            <tr>
                                <td>{d.id}</td>
                                <td>{d.firstName}</td>
                                <td>{d.lastName}</td>
                            </tr>
                        )
                    })}
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <section className="pagination">
                <button>first</button>
                <button>previous</button>
                <button>next</button>
                <button>last</button>
            </section>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On component mount, you can sort the data into an object map, and update the current page key dynamically based on which button is pushed:

https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-turing-mtbpy?file=/src/App.js